# Function does not modify variable in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I create two lists, a, b with 10 random numbers from 0 to 61 and then I compare the lists if they have common numbers or not.

I store the common numbers in a separate list.

If the list does have numbers in it the commonCount is going up and if the list is empty the noCommonCount is going up.

But when I want to print the counts after I rand the function 10 times it prints out 0.

I don't know why because I declared the variables commonCount and noCommonCount outside the function.

```
import random

noCommonCount = 0
commonCount = 0

def list_overlap():
    a = []
    b = []

    count = 0

    while count < 10:
        count = count + 1
        a.append(random.randint(0, 61))
        b.append(random.randint(0, 61))    

    commonNumbers = []

    for i in a:
        if i in b:
            if i not in commonNumbers:
                commonNumbers.append(i)

    if not commonNumbers:
        noCommonCount + 1
    else:
        commonCount + 1


functionCount = 0

while functionCount < 10:
    functionCount = functionCount + 1
    list_overlap()

print(noCommonCount)
print(commonCount)
```

Comment: What is this supposed to do: `noCommonCount + 1`? Does it _modify_ the `noCommonCount` variable? It doesn't, it creates a new one that's one more than `noCommonCount` and immediately discards it.

Comment: Unless you use `global noCommonCount`, functions create local _shadows_ of variables.  As a matter of style, using global variables to store state is often confusing, and you should _return_ your results instead.  And also, you don't actually _assign_ your result to the variable, you just add and throw the result away.

Comment: @Max so I should create and return both noCommonCount and commonCount in the function.

Can you please show me how it's done?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a function modifying a variable declared on outer scope additionally a declaration of the form

```
global variable_name
```

is required in the function (typically directly after function declaration.

Comment: This function doesn't even try to modify the variables, so this won't solve the problem

Comment: @Simplex, well, I would _actually_ modify the variable, with `noCommonCount += 1` and the same for `commonCount`. If you do that, you'll get an error, which'll be solved using the solution in this answer.